# Getting a MySQL table's key and engine information from a statement's metadata using java

Tags: java, mysql, metadata

I am in the process of writing a java class that will read tables from a database that exists on one database server and will then recreate the tables in another database that resides on a different server.

With the above in mind, I am obtaining the most of the tables' metadata from a result set that reads from the source database.  I say most because I am unsure where I can information on the keys, the auto-increment, engine information.
Can I get this information via the statement's metadata?  Or should I be looking elsewhere for this information? Possibly the database's metadata???

If this helps, here is a snippet of the code - as you can see, quite basic stuff.

```
 Statement sourceStmt = sourceConnection.createStatement();
 ResultSet sourceRS = sourceStmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
```

--> this is how I am getting the metadata and am not sure if this is correct
    or not in regards to wanting to get the key and engine type information.

```
sourceDataRS.getMetaData();
```

Any information you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Big picture: What are you trying to accomplish here? Can you simply use the [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) feature?

Comment: The intent is to take a snapshot of the database at a given point in time and then copy it over to a test server for regression testing purposes using a static set of data in the tables.    The process would be run by a user whenever they need to refresh the test database and using replication would take that out of their hands.

Comment: Use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) for that. Don't re-invent the wheel. I suggest using the `--lock-table=false` option so that you don't impact your production environment and the `--compress` option too.

Comment: I'll give that a try - not sure why I did not think about that previously.  I had my java and jdbc glasses on and was not broadening my scope.  Thanks.

Comment: @Asaph... just want to close the loop on this.  Thanks for your suggestion - it is a much easier and cleaner solution to what I wanted to do.